# If the Sums of all $k$-th Powers are Equal then the Terms are Equal

Tags: real-analysis, galois-theory

Consider the following problem:

> Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ be real numbers such that
>   $$a_1^k+\cdots a_n^k= b_1^k+ \cdots+b_n^k$$
>   for all $1\leq k\leq n$.
>   Then there is a bijection $\varphi:\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}\to \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ such that $a_i=b_{\varphi(i)}$ for all $i$.

This can be proved using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), which gives that the polynomials $p(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ and $q(x)=(x-b_1)\cdots(x-b_n)$ are identical.

**My question is**, can this be said about countable sequences.
More precisely, is the following true?

> Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3,\ldots$ be real numbers such that
>   $$a_1^k+a_2^k+a_3^k+\cdots = b_1^k+ b_2^k+b_3^k+ \cdots$$
>   are equal for all $k\geq 1$ (Here we insist that both sums are convergent for each $k$).
>   Then there is a bijection $\varphi:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $a_i=b_{\varphi(i)}$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma.** If $c_n\in\Bbb R$, $|c_n|<1$ for all $n$ and $s_k:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^k$ converges absolutely for all $k\ge 1$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty}s_k=0$.

*Proof.*
The series with $k=2$ converges absolutely, hence so do all series  with $k\ge 2$.
Thus for $k>2$, we have
$$ \left|\sum_n c_n^k\right|\le \sum_n|c_n|^k\le |c_1|^{k-2}\sum_nc_n^2\to 0.$$
$\square$

For $c>0$ and $m\in\Bbb N_0$, consider
$$\tag1 \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(c^{-k}\sum_na_n^k-(-1)^km\right).$$
Using the lemma, we see that

- For $c=\max |a_n|$, this limit exists iff and $m=\#\{\,n\mid a_n=-c\,\}$ and then it equals $\#\{\,n\mid a_n=c\,\}$.
- For $c>\max|a_n|$, the limit exists only for $m=0$ and then it equals $0$.
- For $c<\max|a_n|$, the limit does not exist for any choice of $m$.

Thus from merely considering the sequence $\{\sum_na_n^k\}_k$, we can read off the following properties of $\{a_n\}_n$: The maximal absolute value of its terms as well as the multiplicity of the positive and negative of this maximum.
We conclude that $\{b_n\}_n$ has the same maximal absolute value with the same multiplicities by sign. Thus we can put these $\pm$maximal values of both sequences in bijection. After removing these $\pm$maximal terms, we repeat the process, thereby bijecting the terms with second-largest absolute value, and so on. In the limit, this gives us a permutation of $\Bbb N$ as desired.

Comment: For the proof of the lemma, must you also assume that $c_1 = \sup \{c_n\}$?

Comment: It seems like there is a typo in your first dot point. "this limit exists iff and..."